# insert into mysql problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 2 fields (`name`, `confirm`).
`confirm` is of type `tinyint` because I want to put in 0 or 1

Now I want to put 1 in `confirm`; is this statement correct?

```
if($row['confirm']==0)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO opt (confirmed) values('0')";
    echo 'The user selected options has confirmed';
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. It almost sounds like you already have the name in the table and you just want to UPDATE the confirmed field for a paticular name. No?

Answer (score 5):

The statement you've written is only correct if you also want the associated 'name' field to be NULL.

If you actually want both fields to be populated you should do:

```
INSERT INTO opt (name, confirmed) VALUES (?, ?)
```

and then use the `mysqli` or `PDO` family of functions to bind the `?` parameters to the user-supplied values.  This is necessary to protected your database against SQL injection attacks.

I would also consider adding another couple of fields:

- A unique `id` field (MySQL's `auto_increment` is good for this) so that you can delete and/or modify specific records
- A `timestamp` field so that you've got a record (pun not intended) of when this data was added

Answer (score 4):

It really sounds that you want to do an update:

UPDATE opt SET confirmed = 1 WHERE name = '$row[name]'

Right?

Answer (score 2):

When 'confirmed' is a numeric column, then you should not put quotes around the 1.

```
INSERT INTO OPT (confirmed) VALUES (1)
```

Comment: MySQL will quite happily accept numeric values with quotes around them.

Comment: MySQL will happily accept a lot of things that should be avoided, or that are considered to be bad practice ...

Answer (score 0):

Everything the previous posters said +: If you only have two possible values for the "confirmed" field then make it a ENUM.